# How to set manual crop to be compulsory for image?

Tags: 7, media

I searched a lot for this problem but not getting any solution.
Any help is very appreciate.

I am using [Manual Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop) (7.x-1.5) module for cropping the images. 
But problem is that I want to set cropping to be compulsory for image. I did not find any option in manual crop setting to set it as required.

Comment: That's not good UX really, what if a user is uploading a perfectly cropped image already? Forcing them to crop it again would be annoying and unproductive. It comes down to this: what are you planning to use as the trigger that lets you know whether the crop has been used, or not?

Comment: Yes @Clive, In my case client requirement is, cropping is compulsory even user upload cropped image again.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, though - there's a default crop when you upload the image, right? So what distinguishes that default crop from one that the user has chosen manually? What if the default crop is actually perfect for the user's image, and nothing needs to change? How are you going to validate that the image has been "manually cropped" in that scenario? You need to come up with your own criteria for that first, then you can think about how it might be implemented

Comment: You are right @Clive, as per UX it is not good idea to crop image which is already cropped. And also right that, manual crop set default cropping area on image(I am using overlay). But if user cancel, or click on outside of cropped image area and click on save. then how I can inform to user please crop image(If image is not cropped). In this case I am facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by using [hook_node_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7.x).